# Azure Pipeline: Msiexec does not terminate if waited for

Tags: azure-pipelines, windows-installer

In an Azure pipeline, I run a powershell script for installing a msi file. I want to evaluate the exit code of the process therefore I wait for it. But if I do so, this task runs for ever, "Wait-Process" will not return. Here is my script:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: '$msiFile =  Join-Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)  "/someMSIfile.msi";
      $proc = Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i, $msiFile , /quiet, /passive" -NoNewWindow -PassThru;
      Wait-Process -InputObject $proc;
      if($proc.ExitCode -ne 0) {Exit 1};'
```

Problem: If I evaluate the exit code immediately, it is always non zero, i.e. failure. If I wait for the process, it will not end.
On the other hand, if I just call Start-Process without evaluating the exit code, the installation will run properly and terminates after ca. 60 seconds. But if I do so, and there is some error, the script will also exit successfully.